# Asterisk 1.4 -- SQL -- how to determine transferred and missed calls by certain queue

Tags: mysql, sql, queue, asterisk

Is it possible to determine, if a call was ended in the target queue (let's say 720) or it was transferred and answered in another queue (let's say 721)?

Is there a parameter that describes transferred call state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no easy way

You will have only answered/hanguped state in queue_log.

To manage transfer you need also add special dialplan or event listener.

Simple way - add in dialplan some variable like __ENTERED_QUEUE=720(duble __ mean it have be moved to sub-channels on new channels create) and read that variable in dialplan.

More complex way - AMI event listener which track calls and mark it.

Comment: Okie, let's imagine, that i've added a variable to dialplan, in which table and column i can find a marker?

Comment: That depend of you mind. You can put variable into any cdr column or use variable to check it from other queue.

Answer (score 0):

There is [a patch](http://forums.digium.com/viewtopic.php?t=4073) for Asterisk 1.4 (which is way too old by the way) to write a queue log to [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL).

But you need to recompile.